# How do I setup javascript/node.js/npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, notepad++

Everytime I try to figure this out I end up on the same pages with the same confusing terminology that doesn't explain anything. This is what I have:

1. installed notepad++ with recommended settings.
2. installed 17 recommended plugins for notepad++
3. installed node.js and all recommended software included in the node.js lts .msi file.

step 1 of the tutorial? create a new directory for the project and use npm init inside of it so we can start keeping track of our packages. problem? I can create a new directory with ease, but where am I supposed to run npm init FROM? presumably some type of console but idk what console, I have like 8 of them after installing node.js, and none of them recognize any commands that I know. Can someone please explain this to me as if I were a 5 year old?

Comment: It's done from terminal. The tutorial should tell you what you need to know before going through it. If you know nothing about installing software from terminals then you should start from there.

Comment: @MannyAlvarado I've installed from terminal on linux but not on windows (which is what I'm working on atm), and I have tried running these commands on the windows powershell, but it doesn't recognize the commands. and the tutorial isn't telling me anything beyond what I've shared in my question.

Comment: Windows is a bit strict with installing stuff through powershell. Trying right clicking powershell and click on "run as administrator" and try the whole thing again.

Comment: administrator privileges *shouldn't* be needed. If the terminal isn't "recognizing any commands", then your path likely isn't setup correctly for node.js development... which is a whole nother topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

all you should need to do is to install node.js from the org website, from there just open cmd or terminal and not any other fancy terminals I would recommend to use VSC but that is up to you after all

if you open cmd, cd into the directory.

then npm init and follow the instructions from the terminal.

Comment: I swear I tried this and it didn't work before, but it worked this time. I have no idea what I did differently but thank you :D

Comment: have a good one with node.js